# What's the best cli parser for scala

Tags: scala, command-line-interface

I want to write a command line interface for my application. What's the best tools for this job? I wanna a REPL interface like sbt console

Comment: What do you want to do with your CLI that you can't do with something like `jline`?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way IMHO:

- use https://github.com/scopt/scopt for parsing command line arguments and then
- run http://ammonite.io/#Embedding to simply start Scala REPL on steroids with some classes already imported and objects already instantiated.